# Precompile error when push to Heroku Rails app with yarn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, yarnpkg

I have a ROR app where I have installed **toaster** and **jQuery** using **yarn**: `yarn add jquery ; yarn add toastr`. Also add their configuration to application.js:

```js
// app/assets/application.js

//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require toastr/toastr
```

Also update application.scss:

```css
app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

@import "toastr/toastr";
```

App tested locally and work good. But when I try to push it to Heroku I got this error:

```sh
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
remote:        Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
remote:        I, [2020-12-01T12:43:31.158434 #1643]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_7363272e/public/assets/application-2b2ad3277391444ddcebbd59536eb9b2f05b9a3ad61300e3ed828b7533f992fb.js
remote:        I, [2020-12-01T12:43:31.159231 #1643]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_7363272e/public/assets/application-2b2ad3277391444ddcebbd59536eb9b2f05b9a3ad61300e3ed828b7533f992fb.js.gz
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        SassC::SyntaxError: Error: File to import not found or unreadable: toastr/toastr.
remote:                on line 2:1 of app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
remote:        >> @import "toastr/toastr";
...
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
```

What do I need to do for fix that ?

Comment: best way is to use https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/yarnpkg/yarn this yarn build pack in heroku and precompile all asset before pushing to heroku and if that not worked for you please continue to use this gem https://github.com/tylergannon/toastr-rails

Comment: @adityapandit17 thanks, i thought about it but haven't tried it yet

Comment: `heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs` resolved my problem, because of yarn I need to use "Multiple Buildpacks" more info here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app

Comment: Yeah roman, I am glad my answer helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use `elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/yarnpkg/yarn` this yarn build pack in Heroku and precompile all asset before pushing to Heroku and if that not work for you please continue to use this gem `github.com/tylergannon/toastr-rails`